# Erro ao gerar gráfico com o pacote ggplot2 no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary

Olá, busco um auxílio para aprimorar um script em R. Desenvolvo ele com o auxílio do pacote ggplot2. Pretendo mostrar um gráfico com media e erro padrão e os pontos do conjunto de dados. Para isso usei as camadas "geom_errorbar()"e "geom_dotplot()" .

Tenho encontrado o erro : "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'PV.y' not found".

Creio que o erro está na camada "geom_errorbar()". Alguém pode me indicar o que está errado? Segue o exemplo do script:

```
gmed <-read.csv("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RSpq7Tpxzt_eHEwwWzh2vPJJ1ddU1I0N",header=T, sep=',')
##gráfico
require(Rmisc)
require(ggplot2)
require(EnvStats)
require(sciplot)
require(dplyr)
#
gpv <- summarySE(gmed, measurevar="PV", groupvars=c("INT"))
summarygpv <- ggplot( gpv, aes(x="INT", y= "PV", fill= "INT"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("S", "P", "G", "F"))+ #alterar ordem ítens 
legenda
  geom_dotplot(binwidth= 0.5,
               binaxis="y",
               stackdir = "center") +
  geom_errorbar(aes (ymin=PV.y-se,
                     ymax=PV.y+se),
                width = 0.25,
                size=0.25)+
  xlab("Tratamentos") +
  ylab(" Posição Vertical (cm)") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("N", "==",N,sep = "")),
            parse = TRUE,
            y=-0.15)+
  geom_point(aes(y=PV.y),
             size=1,show.legend = F) +
  theme_bw () +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey75","grey25"))
summarygpv
```

Comment: Pelo que aparenta o erro a variável "PV.y" não foi encontrada, verifique se é esse mesmo o nome em gpv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O principal problema era chamar as variáveis a serem plotadas como strings, colocando-as entre aspas. Veja que no meu código abaixo eu chamo elas diretamente.

```
ggplot(gpv, aes(x=INT, y=PV, fill=INT)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("S", "P", "G", "F")) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth= 0.5, binaxis="y", stackdir = "center") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=PV-se, ymax=PV+se), width=0.25, size=0.25) +
  labs(x="Tratamentos", y="Posição Vertical (cm)") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste("N", "==",N,sep = "")), parse = TRUE, y=c(17.5, 15, 15, 22.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=PV), size=1, show.legend = F) +
  theme_bw () +
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.25, end=0.75)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além desta alteração, mudei a posição dos textos `N=?`. Acredito que fica melhor desta forma, pois a janela gráfica tem um dot muito distante dos demais. Daria pra colocar embaixo (ou em cima) de cada um dos dots, mas aí tem que aumentar os limites do gráfico para que não falte espaço.

Paralelo a isso, não sei o `geom_point()` é necessário, pois ele deixa um ponto preto no meio dos dots maiores. Eu mantive no meu resultado, mas eu tiraria do gráfico final.

Por fim, colocar `scale_fill_grey`, com valores de cinza inicial e final, é mais prático do que ficar definindo um valor de cinza diferente para cada nível da variável Tratamento.

Comment: grato pela contribuição e dicas. Contudo, gostaria de ter as observações representadas no gráfico por pontos junto ao ponto médio e barras de erro.

Comment: Para esta implementação teria uma camada mais apropriada ex, geom_dotplot() ou geom_point() ?